# C++ basics: ranged based for-loop and passing C-style arrays to functions

Tags: c++, arrays, parameter-passing, ranged-loops

I'm trying to learn C++ but I just can't wrap my head around this code here, despite spending a good amount of time searching for an answer:

```
#include <iostream>

void printArray1(int (&array)[3]) {
    for(int x : array)
        std::cout << x << " ";
}

void printArray2(int array[]) { 
    for(int x : array) // compiler error, can't find begin and end
        std::cout << x << " ";
}

int main() {
    int a[3] = {34,12,88};

    for(int x : a)
        std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    printArray1(a);
    printArray2(a);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In printArray1, we are receiving a parameter that is a reference to an array of size 3. Does this mean we are receiving the address of the entire array or are we just receiving an address to the first element in the array of size 3? Also, how is this parameter then passed to the loop?

In printArray2, we are receiving a pointer to the first element in the array, correct? In other words, we are also receiving an address just like in printArray1? Thus, the ranged-based for-loop in this function will not compile because we have no size data for the array, right?

Finally, when we attempt to print with the ranged-based for-loop in main, what exactly are we passing to the loop? Is it a pointer to the first element in the array here, and if so, why does it compile if the for-loop in printArray2 did not accept the pointer?

My understanding of C++ is still quite elementary so I really appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: did you see it yourself by debugging your program? what does it print?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The range-based for loop works for all types that can be used with `std::begin` and `std::end`.

Arrays and pointers are not the same. An array has a fixed size, a pointer does not. Hence `std::begin` and `std::end` work for arrays - but not for pointers. That also explains why the range-based for loop works for one, but not the other.

Arrays may also decay to pointers. This happens, for example, when passed to functions that take a pointer parameter. Or, when passed to functions which take an indeterminate-sized array parameter (which is effectively the same as a pointer parameter). When that happens, size information is lost again.

So it depends on how you define the function. The first function takes an array, the second a pointer. That's why the first preserves size information and the loop works.

However, it limits what the function can take. The second function can take an `int b[2]`, while the first cannot.

Comment: So basically, when I use the identifier _a_ in main(), I'm passing an array type to the loop, correct? But _a_ is still an address to the first element in the array, like a pointer, except it has a fixed size, as you said?

Comment: Not quite, `a` is not "an address to the first element in the array", at no point. `a` is *the* array, which has a fixed size. You should not even think of arrays and pointers as the same types, arrays have nothing to do with addresses, the only relation is that arrays can *decay* into pointers on assignment (whether it's assigning it to a variable or passing it as a function parameter). Look up array decay to find out more about it.

Comment: Ah ok, so is it valid to say that there is no decay to the array as we pass _a_ to the range-based loop, and that there is no decay as we pass _a_ to the first function, where the parameter is a reference, yes?

Comment: Correct. Decay only happens on calling of the latter function, because arrays can implicitly convert to pointers. That's where size information is lost.

Comment: Perfect, I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. Also, as @Claymore pointed out, you should look into using `std::array` instead of raw arrays when possible. If this is just an exercise it's fine, it's good to know these mechanics for when the need arises, but for productive coding, proper containers always win. `std::array` for statically sized, ordered, contiguous containers and `std::vector` for dynamically sized, ordered, contiguous containers. There are plenty other containers which are appropriate for different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

In the `[3]` case, the function knows how big the array is from its type.  A reference is often implemented as a pointer to the referred to thing, but in C++ great lengths are gone through to leave that an implementation detail (which sometimes enables optimizations).  References are *aliases* for data elsewhere, subly different than pointers (which are like postal addresses).  Iteration is easy when the compiler has the length, and C++ does the right thing.

In the `[]` case, this is C style syntax.  It is not a reference.  It means the same as `int * array`.  The size of the array is neither part of tue compile time type (within the function), nor runtime state (which is a single int pointer).  Clearly iteration is impossible without the length.

Answer (score 0):

According to cppreference about [arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) and [Ranged-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

In *printArray1*, the *array* argument is an array of *int references* which will each one reference the first 3 values of the array that is passed as an argument.

In *printArray2*, the *array* argument is a pointer than points to the first value of the array that is passed as an argument. With it, you can access all values of the array.

Finally, it is not a pointer but just a reference for the *a* array.
In that particular case, what is important to know is that for each iteration, a copy of the iterated value will be performed to the *x* variable. 
If you want to prevent all those copies from happening, you should declare a reference instead.

Example:

```
for(int &x : a)
    std::cout << x << " ";
```

Btw, you should also take a look at the [array container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which is the modern-style array.